# Что это за запрос к bd?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

```
function get_user(){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    global $site_city_id;
    $user_id = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['userId']));
    $user = (new DbQuery())
        ->select('*', 'users')
        ->compare('id', $user_id)
        ->result()[0];
    if ($user) {
        die(json_encode($user));
    } else {
        $command = new DbQuery();
        $command->select('office_phone', 'e_offices')
            ->compare('city_id', $site_city_id)
            ->limit(1);
        $office_phone = $command->result()[0]['office_phone'];
        preg_match(
            '/^\.*((?:\+?\d{1,3})[\s-]?(?:\(?\d{2,5}\)?)?[\s-]?(?:\d{1,3}[-]?\d{1,3}[-]?\d{1,3}))/',
            $office_phone,
            $matches
        );
        die(json_encode(array(
            'phone' => $matches[0]
        ))); // первый телефон
    }
}
```

Что это за запрос и в чем отличие от SELECT * FROM users ? Мне нужна наводка на то что гуглить.

Comment: А что тут не понятно? Переменная `$user` сама за себя говорит.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте  запрос текстом, а не картинкой. Текст вопроса должен полностью индексироваться.

Comment: *в чем отличие от `SELECT * FROM users` ?* Наличием условия отбора (секции `WHERE`).

Comment: Выборка пользователя по `$user_id` - только если там прилетает число, понять не могу, на какой там `strip_tags` и `trim`? Когда просто можно было сделать `cast` - `$user_id = (int) $_REQUEST['userId'];` хотя не рекомендую использовать `$_REQUEST`, рекомендую `filter_input`.

Comment: @Akina подскажите как сформировать WHERE `no_site`= false

Comment: @bobert89 `->where('no_site',false)` как-то так, типо того

Comment: @bobert89 а вообще погуглите что-нибудь по типу: "ООП PHP запросы к БД", ну или документацию поройте по Вашему фреймворку, там должно быть вполне себе хорошо описано, что и как, и какие встроенные фичи для работ с базами данных имеются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это запрос, написанный при помощи **построителя запросов**. Это позволяет сделать код более читаемым и облегчить переход к другой **СуБД** [тык](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-query-builder/)